Random MySQL Server 8 on Ubuntu 20.0.4 - 2 processes trying to run gets stuck on Loading Status
I have been running into this issue now for the last 2 weeks. Our Ubuntu 20.04 server was stable and running without issue until one day it pinged me a 500 error with UpTime Robot monitoring.
When I run sudo aa-status, it tells me 2 processes are running:
2 processes have profiles defined.
2 processes are in enforce mode.

I have to kill all mysql processes with service mysql stop && pkill -f mysql then I restart mysql and it runs fine until I try to apt-get upgrade or several days later it fails again (showing 2 processes are running), trying to run 2 processes again.
Log during installation of apt-get upgrade:
    Installing new version of config file /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real ...
    snapd.failure.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
    snapd.snap-repair.service is a disabled or a static unit not running, not starting it.
    Failed to restart snapd.mounts-pre.target: Operation refused, unit snapd.mounts-pre.target may be requested by dependency only (it is configured to refuse manual start/stop).
    See system logs and 'systemctl status snapd.mounts-pre.target' for details.
    Could not execute systemctl:  at /usr/bin/deb-systemd-invoke line 142.
    Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) ...
    mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
    mysqld is running as pid 970329 – /* it gets stuck here and I have to kill the upgrade process. */

Here's the mysql activity error.log:
2024-06-27T06:46:34.502107Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3).
2024-06-27T06:46:38.837191Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T06:46:39.717149Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) starting as process 947303
2024-06-27T06:46:39.734931Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-06-27T06:46:40.491766Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-06-27T06:46:41.065186Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-06-27T06:46:41.065256Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-06-27T06:46:41.076019Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2024-06-27T06:46:41.097070Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.kMoGt0DxMK/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T06:46:41.096966Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-06-27T06:46:41.160863Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3).
2024-06-27T06:46:42.568082Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T06:46:43.589403Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) starting as process 947384
2024-06-27T06:46:43.597771Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-06-27T06:46:44.521097Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-06-27T06:46:44.954169Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-06-27T06:46:44.954260Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-06-27T06:46:44.961391Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2024-06-27T06:46:44.973781Z 6 [ERROR] [MY-000061] [Server] 1290  The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement.
2024-06-27T06:46:44.980218Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-06-27T06:46:44.980391Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.MGSbEUbdjf/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T09:30:50.847746Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) starting as process 952056
2024-06-27T09:30:50.854193Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-06-27T09:30:51.469514Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T09:30:52.469724Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T09:30:53.469927Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T09:30:54.470109Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T09:30:55.470313Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T09:30:56.470508Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T09:30:57.470715Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T09:30:58.470943Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T09:56:40.974503Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-013538] [InnoDB] Doublewrite file create failed: ./#ib_16384_0.dblwr
2024-06-27T09:56:40.974521Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error I/O error.
2024-06-27T09:56:41.474982Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-06-27T09:56:41.475208Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-06-27T09:56:41.475229Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-06-27T09:56:41.476014Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T10:02:08.521653Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) starting as process 953520
2024-06-27T10:02:08.528925Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-06-27T10:02:09.419385Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:02:10.419610Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:02:11.419837Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:02:12.420034Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:02:13.420225Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:02:14.420418Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:02:15.420657Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:02:16.420837Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:02:17.421013Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:02:18.421204Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:02:19.421393Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:03:49.441851Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
2024-06-27T10:03:49.441862Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
2024-06-27T10:03:49.441886Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012215] [InnoDB] Cannot open datafile './ibdata1'
2024-06-27T10:03:49.441894Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012959] [InnoDB] Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit i>
2024-06-27T10:03:49.441902Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file.
2024-06-27T10:03:49.942639Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-06-27T10:03:49.942821Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-06-27T10:03:49.942841Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-06-27T10:03:49.943550Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T10:03:50.380882Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) starting as process 953591
2024-06-27T10:03:50.387240Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-06-27T10:05:23.929456Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:05:24.929619Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:05:25.929964Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:05:26.930178Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:05:27.930394Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:05:28.930640Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:05:29.930861Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:05:30.931112Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012574] [InnoDB] Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 11
2024-06-27T10:05:30.931184Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012592] [InnoDB] Operating system error number 11 in a file operation.
2024-06-27T10:05:30.931195Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012596] [InnoDB] Error number 11 means 'Resource temporarily unavailable'
2024-06-27T10:05:30.931217Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012215] [InnoDB] Cannot open datafile './ibdata1'
2024-06-27T10:05:30.931225Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012959] [InnoDB] Could not open or create the system tablespace. If you tried to add new data files to the system tablespace, and it failed here, you should now edit i>
2024-06-27T10:05:30.931252Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-012930] [InnoDB] Plugin initialization aborted with error Cannot open a file.
2024-06-27T10:05:31.431587Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-010334] [Server] Failed to initialize DD Storage Engine
2024-06-27T10:05:31.431810Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2024-06-27T10:05:31.431865Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2024-06-27T10:05:31.432553Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T10:07:58.815787Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3).
2024-06-27T10:08:00.269527Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T10:08:58.459081Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) starting as process 953915
2024-06-27T10:08:58.467408Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-06-27T10:08:59.177822Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-06-27T10:08:59.453877Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-06-27T10:08:59.453921Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-06-27T10:08:59.467068Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-06-27T10:08:59.467164Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T10:25:16.758378Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3).
2024-06-27T10:25:18.220028Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T10:25:18.749483Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) starting as process 970327
2024-06-27T10:25:18.764173Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-06-27T10:25:19.522920Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-06-27T10:25:19.850388Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-06-27T10:25:19.850418Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-06-27T10:25:19.853588Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2024-06-27T10:25:19.861397Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-06-27T10:25:19.861462Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.YGv9RZWmRV/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T10:25:19.895543Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3).
2024-06-27T10:25:21.354827Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T10:25:22.293591Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) starting as process 970408
2024-06-27T10:25:22.303725Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-06-27T10:25:23.245419Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-06-27T10:25:23.665054Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-06-27T10:25:23.665116Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-06-27T10:25:23.671104Z 0 [Warning] [MY-011810] [Server] Insecure configuration for --pid-file: Location '/tmp' in the path is accessible to all OS users. Consider choosing a different directory.
2024-06-27T10:25:23.680769Z 6 [ERROR] [MY-000061] [Server] 1290  The MySQL server is running with the --skip-grant-tables option so it cannot execute this statement.
2024-06-27T10:25:23.683508Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-06-27T10:25:23.683614Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3'  socket: '/tmp/tmp.8vsb0UM37c/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T10:27:14.688388Z 0 [System] [MY-013172] [Server] Received SHUTDOWN from user <via user signal>. Shutting down mysqld (Version: 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3).
2024-06-27T10:27:16.105078Z 0 [System] [MY-010910] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: Shutdown complete (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3)  (Ubuntu).
2024-06-27T10:28:07.280103Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) starting as process 989991
2024-06-27T10:28:07.298250Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2024-06-27T10:28:08.250642Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2024-06-27T10:28:08.620094Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010068] [Server] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
2024-06-27T10:28:08.620151Z 0 [System] [MY-013602] [Server] Channel mysql_main configured to support TLS. Encrypted connections are now supported for this channel.
2024-06-27T10:28:08.634717Z 0 [System] [MY-011323] [Server] X Plugin ready for connections. Socket: /var/run/mysqld/mysqlx.sock
2024-06-27T10:28:08.634806Z 0 [System] [MY-010931] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld: ready for connections. Version: '8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  (Ubuntu)

I am not sure why it keeps trying to load 2 processes of mysql. Not sure where else to look. Tried several solutions, and still no fix yet. The upgrade issue is a big one. I can't upgrade without it trying to run 2 mysql processes. Anyone else run into this on Ubuntu 20.04?
Articles I have tried as solutions, no fix so far:
https://www.middlewareinventory.com/blog/mysql-error-unable-lock-ibdata1/
https://fixyacloud.wordpress.com/2020/01/26/mysql-keeps-crashing-innodb-unable-to-lock-ibdata1-error-11/
UPDATE:
As requested with the command: ps aux | grep mysqld
mysql     989991  1.9  5.3 5025560 880336 ?      Ssl  10:28   4:11 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root     1001871  0.0  0.0   7016  2052 pts/0    S+   14:04   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld

My dev server is a replica, but I see this difference with that command on:
mysql     211614  1.5 25.7 3158596 2096108 ?     Ssl  Jun15 263:23 /usr/sbin/mysqld
root      931997  0.0  0.0   7016  2076 pts/2    S+   14:04   0:00 grep --color=auto mysqld

Here's all thats installed with apt list --installed | grep mysql
dbconfig-mysql/jammy,now 2.0.21 all [installed,automatic]
mysql-client-8.0/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mysql-client-core-8.0/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mysql-common/jammy,now 5.8+1.0.8 all [installed,automatic]
mysql-server-8.0/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mysql-server-core-8.0/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 amd64 [installed,automatic]
mysql-server/jammy-updates,jammy-security,now 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 all [installed]
php-mariadb-mysql-kbs/jammy,now 1.2.12-1 all [installed,automatic]
php-mysql/jammy,now 2:8.3+94+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+2 all [installed,automatic]
php8.1-mysql/jammy,now 8.1.29-1+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed]
php8.3-mysql/jammy,now 8.3.8-2+ubuntu22.04.1+deb.sury.org+1 amd64 [installed,automatic]


Please edit the question and add with the edit command all the things you have tried and the errors or messages you get when you do them.

I have added the 2 articles I have tried so far with their commands or recommendations. Server version: 8.0.37-0ubuntu0.22.04.3 (Ubuntu)

Can you edit your question and add the output of ps aux | grep mysqld

I am wondering if the root pts/0 is the issue?? Everyone else seems to have pts2

No, root pts/0 is the grep command I asked you to write. You are seeing root because you executed it with sudo or because you are logged in as root.

I see only one instance of mysql running. You mentioned that you have two? Can you share more details about how you installed mysql.

Please edit you question with the output of these 2 commands: apt list --installed | grep mysql and apt list --installed | grep mariadb

I only discovered 2 processes due to checking the sql log file above when I found our website down. Saw the lock file issue, then discovered 2 processes were running.  Downside, it keeps happening...this is the third time our site went down, after researching finding MySQL was stuck on Loading/start. My dev server does not do that. I tried to upgrade packages also this morning, and ran into mysql getting hung up, due to another process being started during the upgrade. Not sure what's going on! So trying to see if anyone else has had this issue.

Are you looking for a way to fix it, because I can give you a "solution", but its a bit extreme :) However, if you want to know why this happened, I can probably figure out a better way to fix it, but you will have to provide more details.

What I have above is all I have. The two experiences, it going down randomly (mysql getting stuck after combing through logs finding its trying to run two processes) and trying to upgrade packages. Not much else to tell! Everything log wise is up there...I think that's as detailed as I can get!

You mentioned that you are using Ubuntu 20.04. However, the packages you have installed are for 22.04.

FIXED!
A couple of things, I had to reduce the RAM, had to update the configuration for ElasticSearch, it was taking up more than it should of RAM resources (75%).
Secondly, I had one line in a file I used way back when we created the server and lost the Root password, /etc/mysql/mysql.conf.d/reset-mysql-password.cnf, --skip-grant-tables. THAT WAS CAUSING THE MYSQL HANG UP. I removed it, restarted, updated the broken install of mysql-server-8.0 and FIXED. Such a small silly thing leftover that reeked havoc on my server causing hang up issues! Take notes, if you ever reset your password for root, be sure to remove that line after you are done with the task. Good lord I had no idea how that can effect package updates for Ubuntu and cause hangup problems.
